# Delete NULLs from std::string

Tags: c++, string, null, gdb, stringstream

I'm using a third party code which has its own implementation for std::ostream operator<<, to handle the third party's type.
I'm using stringstream for this output - like:

```
string ToString(const thrdPartyType& structure)
{
stringstream outputStream;
outputStream<<structure;
return outputStream.str();
}
...
string str = ToString(structure);
...
```

This structure contains pointer members, which are set to NULL. When using the operator<< and the assignment of `str()` into a string, I see (via gdb - `print str`) that there are many leading '\000' characters, then the string data I need.

How can I trim those NULLs in order to get only the real, not empty data?

P.S. The exact code works fine in Windows VC++...

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds as though the third party code is broken. Maybe you should file a bug report.

Comment: Firstly is outputStream printable? On what platform are you running gdb. If this is printing pointers are they 64-bit where it is not working which may explain why you see more zero characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a workoround like this?

```
string ToString(const thrdPartyType& structure)
{
   stringstream outputStream;
   outputStream << structure;

   stringstream workaround;
   while(! outputStream.eof ) {
   char t;
   outputStream >> t;
   if(t != '\0')
    workaround << t;
   }

   return workaround .str();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a small improvement - define char t outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you have **boost** available, something like the following will replace all instances of null in a string with another value.

```
boost::replace_all(str,boost::as_array(""),"NULL");
```

For example

```
char buf[10] = "hello";
string str(buf,buf+10);
boost::replace_all(str,boost::as_array(""),"NULL");
cout << str << endl;
```

Produces the following output

```
helloNULLNULLNULLNULLNULL
```